# How to generate a version1 uuid in Cockroachdb

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, cockroachdb, timeuuid

Our current datastore is Cassandra. We're planning to move away from it towards Cockroachdb wherein we need to refactor our code(Spring boot). The current scripts use the datatype `'timeuuid'` which gives a version1 uuid in Cassandra. Now, I need a similar datatype in CockroachDb which will be feasible to store the existing data (when we migrate in bulk) and also to create new data for that column (`'created_at'`).

I found a builtin in CockroachDb docs which is related to ulid but ulid's format is different from a version1 uuid.

Any ideas what can I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CockroachDB is adding support for the `uuid_generate_v1()` builtin function [in v22.2](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/pull/80204), which is coming out later in 2022. Until then, you'd need to generate the UUID within your application.

Comment: I am now generating the timebased uuids in my code and persisting them. There is an endpoint where i need to fetch data between two uuids(timestamp based). Earlier in Cassandra, the native sql would be just using > and < for the column. How do I compare timebased uuids in Cockroachdb?